# Check if a PT table Data field exists VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

[image]

My code runs perfect... but somehow it adds a data field every time it runs. I tried to test it if it exists with `If pf.Orientation = xlDataField = True Then...("Don't add xlDataField")...` Still no results.

I am pretty sure I am missing something important here otherwise the code runs good. Is there a way not to add another field if it already exists?.

```
Sub Import()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, pvtCache As PivotCache
    Dim wsp As Worksheet
    Dim pf As PivotField, pt As PivotTable

    Set wsp = Sheets("Pivot")
    Set pt = wsp.PivotTables("PivotTable")

    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

    Sheets("TP_Coois").Cells.Replace ",", "", xlPart
    Set pf = pt.PivotFields("Sales")

    If pf.Orientation = xlDataField = True Then  '***I believe here is something wrong***
        pt.PivotCache.Refresh
    Else
        With pf
            .Orientation = xlDataField
            .Function = xlSum
        End With

        pt.PivotCache.Refresh
    End If

End Sub
```

Any Help is appreciated

Comment: is it possible the Sheets("TP_Coois").Cells.Replace ",", "", xlPart is adding cells?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your conditional from:

```
If pf.Orientation = xlDataField = True Then
```

To this:

```
If pf.Orientation = xlDataField Then
```

Comment: Thanks Buddy, I did try it without = True, but still it keps adding the same field.

Comment: Hi Brian, guess what, we were close but the best solution for this problem is 
"If pf.Name = "Sales" Then..." 
All credit to Rory in vbaexpress.com